# Software to form a word frequency list for a Spanish book

Tags: software, spanish, frequency, lemmas

I've actually found [one called "textstat"](http://neon.niederlandistik.fu-berlin.de/en/textstat/), but it doesn't recognize different word forms of one word.

So are there programs that do detect comía, come, cómelo, comiera as forms of comer?

Comment: This is called ["lemmatizing" or "lemmatization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) and is often confused with ["stemming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), which is similar but aims for efficiency at the cost of linguistic accuracy.

Comment: Thanks. Any help on specific apps, that include both lemmatization and frequency list builder features?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Spanish stemming algorithm found at http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/spanish/stemmer.html.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [ISpell](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/ispell.html) or, better yet, [HunSpell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) (for it supports Unicode)?

These are more intended for spelling-correction. However, since they also try to grok the conjugations and flexions for languages with them, they could be helpful. These programs expose an interface so you can call them from other programs (such as a word processor or a browser), you could create a script that reads your text file and calls it continuously not for the sake of spelling but to get the "base" word ("comer" in your example)